# How to get the longest one's sequence in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have some problems with a question that ask me to get  the number of one's in the longest one's sequence in a 16 bit input using a 5 bit number in verilog. For example 
(01110**11111**010101 = 00101 the answer is five duo to the sequence in the middle)
(1111111111111111 = 100000) I would like to know how to do it using both combinational and sequential circuits.

Comment: A typical FSM kinda problem. You can take one register array holding the no of ones so far. Whenever a 1 comes, increment a counter. If a zero comes, compare counter with register, and if it is larger than reg, overwrite it. This is one of many possible ways.

Comment: I am a beginner in this design language so I couldn't understand your advice. Would you please wright the code.

Comment: Nope. Cant really do that. Be specific what part you dont understand.

Comment: Ok first of all i have to use xlinix. second i don't know how to make the module count a series of ones and then stop when a zero comes then start counting again and comparing the second result with the first one

Comment: Looks like you are just getting started using verilog. I would say you get some good book like this -> http://www.amazon.com/FPGA-Prototyping-Verilog-Examples-Spartan-3/dp/0470185325/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1431267160&sr=8-1&keywords=fpga+prototyping+by+verilog+examples  .....and spend some time learning synthesis using verilog.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this question with a shift and kill method.

Let's say you have N input bits and N is 16.

**Step 1)**
Load a N bit wide shift register with your input in parallel. Add a zero bit at LSB.

```
0111 1010 0111 0011|0
```

reset your result counter to 0

**Step 2)**
Perform a 'shift' operation that expands existing zeros to the left neighbor bit.

```
0111 1010 0111 0011|0
0111 0000 0110 0010|0
```

Increment the result counter.

**Step 3)**
Check if the register is all zero.
false -> repeat step 2 and 3
true -> result counter holds your longest one sequence.

Example:

```
0111 1010 0111 0011|0 cnt=0 / input
0111 0000 0110 0010|0 cnt=1
0110 0000 0100 0000|0 cnt=2
0100 0000 0000 0000|0 cnt=3
0000 0000 0000 0000|0 cnt=4 / done
```

Minimum execution time is 1 load and 1 compare -> can be solved in 1 cycle.

Maximum execution time is 1 load and N shifts -> 17 cycles in the example.

Real execution time is 1 load and n shifts if n is the length of the longest one sequence -> 5 cycles in the example.

**How to calculate the bits while shifting?**
Let's name the shift register `a`.

```
a(0) := 0
for i in 1..N-1
  a(i) := a(i) and a(i-1)
next
```

**How many hardware is used?**
- N registers for a
- N LUTs for load and shift before each register
- a ld(N+1) bit counter
- a N bit zero comparator

**On Xilinx hardware:**
Xilinx FPGAs have 6-input LUTs which can be used as 2 5-input LUTs moreover there are 2 FF per LUT. Synthesis can map a 16 bit shift register into only 2 slices and the comperator into a third slice.

**As requested - a 5 bit counter**

```
reg     [4:0]   counter;

always @(posedge Clock)
begin
  if(Reset)
     counter <=      5'b0;
  else if(counter_en)
     counter <=      counter + 1;
end
```

Comment: Didn't understand /:

Comment: Can you be more precise, please. I'll try to explain these parts more in detail.

Comment: can u just build a 5 bits counter in verilog please

Comment: "for i in 1..N-1" ... That's not the syntax I'm familiar with for a Verilog for statement. Is this VHDL? (I'm not too sure about the "..")

Comment: That's pseudo code.